# File paths in a PostGIS Table in QGIS

Tags: postgis, qgis, postgresql

I have a PostGIS table which I have stored the location of some viewpoint photographs. I would like to store the location of the photo file in a field, but when I add a file path in the attribute table dialog in QGIS, QGIS/PostGIS removes '\' and spaces from the path.

Can anyone help me work out why this is? I have done this before without any issues.

If I enter the data through pgAdmin it comes across to QGIS correctly, and I can link to the photographs.

Comment: I just tested this on Ubuntu with QGIS nightly and I cannot reproduce this problem.

Comment: I am using the QGIS-Dev version from OSGeo4W. I just updated it now and the problem is still there when entering data within QGIS. It works fine entering data from pgAdmin.

Answer (score 2):

Try double quoting your paths, or escaping your slashes.
Either

```
"D:\Projects\picture.jpg"
```

or

```
'D:\\Projects\\picture.jpg'
```

should fix you right up.

Comment: See comment to underdarks answer. Putting double quotes doesnt work either - it still removes the \ characters from the path.

Answer (score 0):

In attribute table, you have to escape special characters like \ and space. If you have the following path: "C:\temp\my path" then you need to enter

```
C:\\temp\\my\ path
```

This way you can also enter new lines "\n" and tabs "\t" into a text field.

Comment: This does work first time around. However, if I go back into the field to edit it again, all of the \ are removed (it forgets I escaped them the first time round), so if I wanted to make any edits I would have to use the escape characters each time (not great for my end users). The only way I have got this working is to use a / character instead of a \ (I found this by making the field a file name rather than a line edit widget. When using this method it puts / in the path. This then works with the evis tool and displays the picture.